# What do valgrind additional packages do?

Tags: valgrind

When I installed valgrind, it suggested to install also the following packages:

valgrind-dbg valgrind-mpi kcachegrind alleyoop valkyrie

Can somebody explain, in plain English, what each of them for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you're running debian or a debian-based distribution, such as ubuntu, so a quick visit to debian package archive will give us some basic information about these packages.

In summary, most of those are tools that help processing valgrind output.

- **[valgrind-dbg](https://packages.debian.org/sid/valgrind-dbg)** contains the debug symbols for valgrind. Useful to pinpoint a problem with valgrind itself in the case it crashes. Check [debian documentation](https://wiki.debian.org/DebugPackage) for more details. Also [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/q/215196/248891) might be useful.
- **[valgrind-mpi](https://packages.debian.org/sid/valgrind-mpi)** is a helper library for profiling/debugging applications that use the MPI api. If your application does not use it, it's likely irrelevant for you.
- **[valkyrie](https://packages.debian.org/sid/valkyrie)** is a graphical tool for parsing and analysing the output of `memcheck` (valgrind is composed of several tools, and `memcheck` is one of them). It will show the memory errors detected by `memcheck` alongside the code that generated them.
- **[alleyoop](https://packages.debian.org/sid/alleyoop)** seems to do the same thing as valkyrie but with a different, GNOME based, interface.
- **[kcachegrind](https://packages.debian.org/sid/kcachegrind)** is a graphical tool for parsing and visualisation of the output of the `callgrind` tool, another tool of the valgrind suite.

There's likely other graphical tools for parsing valgrind output in a variaty of formats, these are just the ones that `apt` recommends installing.